# How to use ForkJoin with Observables in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, fork-join

LogDataTransferService:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LogDataTransferService {
  private logs = new Subject<SampleLogModel[]>();
  public logs$ = this.logs.asObservable();

  public collectLogs(logData: SampleLogModel[]): void {
    this.logs.next(logData);
  }

  public getLogs(): Observable<LogModel[]> {
    return this.logs$;
  }
}
```

LogValidationService:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})

export class LogValidationService {
  private errorMessage = new Subject<string[]>();
  public errorMessage$ = this.errorMessage.asObservable();

  public collectErrorMessage(errorMessage: string[]): void {
    this.errorMessage.next(errorMessage);
  }

  public getErrorMessages(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.errorMessage$;
  }
}
```

SampleLogService:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class SampleLogService {

  constructor(
    private logDataTransferService: LogDataTransferService,
    private logValidationService: LogValidationService
  ) {
  }

  public isLogDataValid() {
    const postLogs$ = this.logDataTransferService.getLogs();
    const errors$ = this.logValidationService.getErrorMessage();
    const joined$ = forkJoin(
      postLogs$,
      errors$
  );

    return joined$.subscribe(console.log);
  }

}
```

The problem is that in the SampleLogService forkJoin does not work.
My goal is to use isLogDataValid() method in the components and I need to get Observable values from logDataTransferService and logValidationService to make some checks for validation.

If this can be done with other rxjs operators it is fine, the forkJoin just an example.

Comment: how is not working exactly? you don't get anything from the console log?

Answer (score 0):

`forkJoin` requires all observables to finish to send a result.
`getLogs()` reads from a `subject` which does't finish here.

You might be interested in `combineLatest` which doesn't require that.

Comment: combineLatest does not help too, in my opinion, the problem may be in the services or in the Observables I have created.
Or I am doing something wrong )

Comment: That means one of `postLogs$` or `errors$` is not emitting.